# Emulating Polymorphism without virtual pointers/overhead

Tags: c++, performance, templates, optimization, switch-statement

Before reading I must emphasise I have demanding performance requirements (not premature optimization- processing millions of messages and need to design with performance in mind from the beginning). If I didn't have these requirements I would just use polymorphism.

I am using C++17 and have ~30 different classes/types. Each class uses CRTP to inherit from a Base and has three identical methods:

```
template<class D>
struct Base
{
    // Shared behaviour
}

struct ObjectN : public Base<ObjectN>
{
    void doA(int p);
    void doB(int p);
    void doC(int p);
};
```

Because I am avoiding Polymorphism I just declare the 30 types manually:

```
Object1 _object1;
.
.
Object30 _object30;
```

Currently  I have 3 wrapper methods to invoke the 3 methods across the 30 classes, switching on the object type and invoking the relevant object's method (`doA()`, `doB()` or `doC()`):

```
void callDoA(int object_type)
{
    switch(object_type)
    {
        case Object1:
            _object1.doA();
            break;
        case Object2:
            _object2.doA();
        .
        .
        case Object30:
            _object30.doA();
    }
}

void callDoB(int object_type)
{
    switch(object_type)
    {
        case Object1:
            _object1.doB();
            break;
        case Object2:
            _object2.doB();
        .
        .
        case Object30:
            _object30.doB();
    }
}

void callDoC(int object_type)
{
    switch(object_type)
    {
        case Object1:
            _object1.doC();
            break;
        case Object2:
            _object2.doC();
        .
        .
        case Object30:
            _object30.doC();
    }
}
```

With 30 x 3 case labels this is not good. The design doesn't feel right.

Given the switch statements are effectively identical (except the method called) is there a smarter way I could do this? I was thinking of re-using the switch statement and passing something in? My first though was a lambda but I'm concerned about performance. However, I can't have 90 case labels!

I could put the 30 types within a variant if helps provide a solution?

Comment: Do you know for a fact that a switch is faster than a virtual call? Did you profile?

Comment: There was a presentation at cppcon 2018 where a problem that may be similar to yours has been discussed (https://youtu.be/yy8jQgmhbAU). Basically someone presented an improved approach on designing a css engine for a web browser (or something similar). The way they approached this was to create different collections for every single object type and simply deal with one collection after the other. Not sure if this approach fits your requirements though: Data oriented design very much depends on the operations on the data.

Comment: There's another talk from last years cppcon which covers data oriented design a bit more broadly btw: [Youtube: Data Orientation For The Win! - Eduardo Madrid - CppCon 2021](https://youtu.be/QbffGSgsCcQ)

Comment: `std::visit` of `std::variant` would do something similar to virtual dispatch

Comment: Instead of a switch statement based on object type, what if each object had a function pointer to the implementation of that object's function?  If you need to save space, you could have those function pointers be class variables instead of member variables, since they won't change.  That should be as blazingly fast as possible, and you won't have to maintain federated switch/case "tables" of dispatch.  Instead, each dispatching function pointer is right with the relevant class.  Oh, look, we've recreated virtual function tables.